# Adding a promotional product when a certain cart amount is reached

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I am looking for the right hook in WooCommerce because I need to add a promotional product to the cart when a certain cart amount of is reached, such as 100 conventional units.

I have also used the hook **`'init'`** but I do not think it's right.

Here is my code:

```
function add_free_product_to_cart(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $product_id = 2006; 
    $found = false;
    if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) 
    {
        foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) 
        {
            $_product = $values['data'];
            if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
            $found = true;
        }
        if(!$found)
        {
            $maximum = 100;
            $current = WC()->cart->subtotal;
            if($current > $maximum){
                $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
            }           
        }       
    }   
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'add_free_product_to_cart' );
```

which hook I should use for that purpose?

Or could you give me a related link to to some similar problem?

Thanks

Comment: sorry this error 
must be 
add_action( 'init', 'add_free_product_to_cart' );

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As you are targeting a certain cart amount to add a promotional product in the cart, you could use **`woocommerce_before_calculate_totals`** hook to achieve this with a custom built function.

You have also to remove that promo item if customer update the cart *(which is embed in that custom function too)*.

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'adding_promotional_product', 10, 1 );
function adding_promotional_product( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    $promo_id = 99; // <=== <=== <=== Set HERE the ID of your promotional product
    $targeted_cart_subtotal = 100; // <=== Set HERE the target cart subtotal
    $has_promo = false;
    $subtotal = 0;

    if ( ! $cart->is_empty() ){

        // Iterating through each item in cart
        foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $item_key => $cart_item ){
            $product_id = version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ? $cart_item['data']->id : $cart_item['data']->get_id();
            // If Promo product is in cart
            if( $product_id == $promo_id ) {
                $has_promo = true;
                $promo_key= $item_key;
            } else {
                // Adding subtotal item to global subtotal
                $subtotal += $cart_item['line_subtotal'];
            }
        }
        // If Promo product is NOT in cart and target subtotal reached, we add it.
        if( ! $has_promo && $subtotal >= $targeted_cart_subtotal ) {
            $cart->add_to_cart( $promo_id );
            // echo 'add';
        // If Promo product is in cart and target subtotal is not reached, we remove it.
        } elseif( $has_promo && $subtotal < $targeted_cart_subtotal ) {
            $cart->remove_cart_item( $promo_key );
        }
    }
}
```

This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or in any plugin file.

This code its tested and works.

Related thread: [WooCommerce - Auto add or auto remove a freebie product from cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234409/woocommerce-auto-add-or-auto-remove-a-freebie-product-from-cart/39240824#39240824)

> Code updated on *(2018-10-01)*

Comment: I am only having one issue though. In regards to testing, when I use the arrows on the specific item in the cart to update the number of items in the cart (to reach a certain cart amount) an extra fee is added to the cart amount ONLY UNTIL i refresh the page OR continue to checkout...?? This is a weird issue. Is there anyway I can have the page automatically refresh when the Free/Promo Item is either added or removed to ensure that the customer is looking at the correct amount at all times?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Does this still work? I added it to my functions file and changed the promo id and targeted cart total but the item doesn't get added

Comment: @Rob Just tested the code, It still works perfectly on last woocommerce version 3.7